# View disappears and the first viewcontroller relaunches when app runs in the background

Tags: objective-c

In my app there are two roles: buyers and sellers and there are corresponding viewcontrollers: BuyerViewController and SellerViewController. The default role is buyer but one can register and become a seller from the menu. When the app launches, the BuyerViewController appears. The buyer starts a trade with an online seller. When the trade starts the buyer sees seller's profile in BuyerViewController and the seller sees the buyer's profile information in SellerViewController. The app works perfect in foreground.

However when the phones stay closed like 2-3 minutes and when I go back to the apps, both screens opens the BuyerViewController. The buyer's view clears up: seller's profile disappears in buyers phone, and the SellerViewController completely disappears. Basically both phones goes back to initial state as if app is just launched. If the app stays in background in a shorter time like a minute or less, the views maintains.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen? I will appreciate any help.

```
BuyerViewController:
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate setTradeRole:@"buyer"];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:mapView];

    //checking if user is registered
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if(currentUser.email == nil || currentUser[@"FirstName"] == nil || currentUser[@"LastName"] ==nil || currentUser[@"PictureUrl"] == nil)
    {
        UIStoryboard *LoginStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *LoginVC = [LoginStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FEXLogin"];

        LoginVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

        [self presentViewController:LoginVC animated:NO completion:nil];
        return;
    }


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    sellerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [mapView  setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.00){
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; //needed for IOS 8
    }

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;  //5 meters distance change will trigger update location
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
    //Initial mapView settings
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [mapView  setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.zoomEnabled =YES;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;  
    addressField.hidden = NO;
    editBuyerAddressButton.hidden = NO;

    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:NO]; 

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
    pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:center.latitude longitude:center.longitude];//necessary to assign before [getSellersLocation]

    //make sure in home page everybody is buyer

    if(currentUser)
    {
        [currentUser setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isSeller"];
        [currentUser setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isSelling"];
        [currentUser saveInBackground];
    }

    //adding the buyerPinImage

    buyerPinImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.mapView.center.x-21), (self.mapView.center.y -56), 42, 56)];
    buyerPinImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buyer.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:buyerPinImage];

    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    handleGeocoding = ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        if(error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
        {
            weakSelf.placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

            weakSelf.addressField.hidden = weakSelf.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem ? YES : NO;
            weakSelf.addressField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@ %@ %@ %@",  weakSelf.placemark.thoroughfare,  weakSelf.placemark.subThoroughfare, weakSelf.placemark.postalCode, weakSelf.placemark.locality];
            NSString *undesired = @"(null)";
            NSString *desired   = @"";

            weakSelf.addressField.text = [weakSelf.addressField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:undesired
                                                                                               withString:desired];

            weakSelf.editBuyerAddressButton.hidden = NO;
        }

        if([weakSelf.addressField.text isEqualToString:@"  "])

            weakSelf.addressField.text = @"   Vent venligst";


    };

    CLLocation *plocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:plocation completionHandler: handleGeocoding];


    [self.view addSubview:toCurrentLoc]; //enables button to current location
    [self.view addSubview:callButton]; //enables showing small container view
    [self.view addSubview:containerView]; //enables showing container view
    [self.view addSubview:paymentView]; //enables showing payment view


    navTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
    navTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navTitleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    navTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    navTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor themeColor];
    navTitleLabel.text = @"";
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitleLabel;

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
    buyButton.hidden = NO;
    containerView.hidden = YES;
    callButton.hidden = YES;
    ratingView.hidden = YES;
    [hudContactSellers hide:YES];
    [mapView removeAnnotation:buyersPin];
    tradeState = NoTrade; //notrade
    contactingSellers = NO;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6 target:locationManager selector:@selector(startUpdatingLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //Notification Settings
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listenSeller:) name:@"listenSeller" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listenTradeEnded:) name:@"listenTradeEnded" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listeBuyerResponded:) name:@"listenBuyerResponded" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listenTradeCancelledBySeller:) name:@"listenTradeCancelledBySeller" object:nil];

    // Configure Star Layout
    [ratingView setStepInterval:1];
    [ratingView setValue:5];
    [ratingView setBaseColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [ratingView setMarkFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:32.0f]];

    // Make Sure Button Is Visible    
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:buyButton];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:addressField];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:editBuyerAddressButton];

}
```

Comment: Show your view did load and view did appear methods!!!!!

Comment: move all the code from view did load to view did appear and see if issue still exists or not

Comment: @Mr.T I tried that but the same happened. by the way I don't want the app to go to the viewdidload settings that actually what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the issue. It was a timer running in the background causing all the objects disappear and relaunching the first view. The timer is deactivated before going to background mode and now it is working perfect.